# LINQ - Writing an extension method to get the row with maximum value for each group

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

My application frequently needs to group a table, then return the row with the maximum value for that group.  This is pretty easy to do in LINQ:

```cs
myTable.GroupBy(r => r.FieldToGroupBy)
.Select(r => r.Max(s => s.FieldToMaximize))
.Join(
    myTable,
    r => r,
    r => r.FieldToMaximize,
    (o, i) => i)
```

Now suppose I want to abstract this out into its own method.  I tried writing this:

```cs
public static IQueryable<TSource>
SelectMax<TSource, TGroupKey, TMaxKey>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TGroupKey>> groupKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TMaxKey>> maxKeySelector)
    where TMaxKey : IComparable
{
    return source
        .GroupBy(groupKeySelector)
        .Join(
            source,
            g => g.Max(maxKeySelector),
            r => maxKeySelector(r),
                (o, i) => i);
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't compile: maxKeySelector is an expression (so you can't call it on r, and you can't even pass it to Max.  So I tried rewriting, making maxKeySelector a function rather than an expression:

```cs
public static IQueryable<TSource>
SelectMax<TSource, TGroupKey, TMaxKey>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TGroupKey>> groupKeySelector,
    Func<TSource, TMaxKey> maxKeySelector)
    where TMaxKey : IComparable
{
    return source
        .GroupBy(groupKeySelector)
        .Join(
            source,
            g => g.Max(maxKeySelector),
            r => maxKeySelector(r),
                (o, i) => i);
}
```

Now this compiles.  But it fails at runtime: "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Max'."  This is what I'm stuck on: I need to find the right way to pass maxKeySelector into Max().

Any suggestions?  I'm using LINQ to SQL, which seems to make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to point out that what you're trying to do is even *easier than you think* in LINQ:

```
myTable.GroupBy(r => r.FieldToGroupBy)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.FieldToMaximize).FirstOrDefault())
```

... which should make our lives a little easier for the second part:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource>
SelectMax<TSource, TGroupKey, TMaxKey>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TGroupKey>> groupKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TMaxKey>> maxKeySelector)
    where TMaxKey : IComparable
{
    return source
        .GroupBy(groupKeySelector)
        .Select(g => g.AsQueryable().OrderBy(maxKeySelector).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

The key is that by making your group an `IQueryable`, you open up a new set of LINQ methods that can take actual expressions rather than taking `Func`s. This should be compatible with most standard LINQ providers.

Comment: Well, this is definitely more concise, but unfortunately it doesn't work.  I get pretty much the same error as before: "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'OrderBy'".

Comment: @ctkrohn: What LINQ provider are you using? It's working just fine for me on LINQ to Entities.... and on LINQ to Objects.

Comment: @ctkrohn: Okay, I added a linq-to-sql tag to the question. It looks like LINQ to SQL doesn't support the whole AsQueryable thing. You're going to have to construct a lambda Expression tree that calls the OrderBy and FirstOrDefault methods, and pass that expression to the `Select` method. It's doable, but it'll take more code than I'm willing to write for you. Sorry.

Comment: @ctkrohn:  Based on this answer, I think you should be able to swap the orderby and groupBy commands and still get the same results (as the groupby shouldn't lose the sorting) and that should compile and run with Linq To Sql. Hence the following should work  return source
   .OrderBy(maxKeySelector)
   .GroupBy(groupKeySelector)
   .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault());

Comment: @sgmoore: That doesn't seem to work either.  OrderBy returns an IOrderedEnumerable, so you can't directly call GroupBy on the result.  If you pass it through an IQueryable, it somehow raises a StackOverflowException when it runs.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: I'm marking this as the answer.  Your original method (GroupBy, OrderBy, select FirstOrDefault) is short enough that it's not work factoring out into a separate extension method.  Thanks.

Comment: @ctkrohn: Strange. I tried this and it worked for me in LinqPad. But I would agree with you that the original method is probably enough

Answer (score 4):

Very interesting. Sometimes "dynamic" can cost you more in sheer development and runtime execution than it is worth (IMHO). Nonetheless, here's the easiest:

```
public static IQueryable<Item> _GroupMaxs(this IQueryable<Item> list)
{
    return list.GroupBy(x => x.Family)
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).First());
}
```

And, here's the most dynamic approach:

```
public static IQueryable<T> _GroupMaxs<T, TGroupCol, TValueCol>
    (this IQueryable<T> list, string groupColName, string valueColName)
{
    // (x => x.groupColName)
    var _GroupByPropInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(groupColName);
    var _GroupByParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var _GroupByProperty = Expression
            .Property(_GroupByParameter, _GroupByPropInfo);
    var _GroupByLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TGroupCol>>
        (_GroupByProperty, new ParameterExpression[] { _GroupByParameter });

    // (x => x.valueColName)
    var _SelectParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var _SelectProperty = Expression
            .Property(_SelectParameter, valueColName);
    var _SelectLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TValueCol>>
        (_SelectProperty, new ParameterExpression[] { _SelectParameter });

    // return list.GroupBy(x => x.groupColName)
    //   .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.valueColName).First());
    return list.GroupBy(_GroupByLambda)
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(_SelectLambda.Compile()).First());
}
```

As you can see, I precede my Extension Methods with an underscore. You do not need to do this, of course. Just take the general idea and run with it.

You would call it like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

foreach (Item item in _List
        .AsQueryable()._GroupMaxs<Item, String, int>("Family", "Value"))
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", item.Family, item.Value);
```

Best of luck!

Comment: This looks clever and helpful, but is probably overkill for my purposes.  I'll bookmark this technique in case I have to factor out any other methods, but for now it's probably easier just to write the code in line.

Comment: @ctkrohn, welp, shame on you for asking for such a method in your question. If I were choosing, I would have written it inline, too. But I don't see a more elegant answer to your original question that this. C'est la vie, I suppose.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to write the code that I was too lazy to provide.